# How to run this maven plugin task from command line?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, command-line

I see in [this POM.xml](https://github.com/codenvy/che-core/blob/55af13c6f03bd5eaae5f93f008add55b9c46bb07/ide/che-core-ide-app/pom.xml#L268-L280), there is some code using `exec-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>IDEInjector-client</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>org.eclipse.che.util.IDEInjectorGenerator</mainClass>
            <arguments>
                <argument>--rootDir=${generated.sources.directory}</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</plugin>
```

I wonder is it possible to run it from command line? Because it seems generate some java classes which is used by other files.

**Question**: How can I run it if it's runnable?

Comment: did you solve your issue? you didn't interact much on this thread

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Sorry I had a long leave these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) execution you mentioned has a binding to the `generate-sources` phase, hence it will be automatically invoked as part of your build (a classic `mvn clean install`, for instance), because in Maven [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) are invoked in cascade and the last one will automatically invoke previous phases.

However, there are several ways you can invoke it:

- As part of the Maven build, automatically (Maven will invoke the whole build, hence each and every phase till the `install`, as such any execution listed in the POM with related bindings)

  ```
  mvn clean install
  ```
- As part of an invocation to the specific phase: Maven will invoke all the executions with a bind to it (and any previous phase), hence not only the specific execution you mentioned

  ```
  mvn generate-sources
  ```
- Only the specific execution, since [Maven **3.3.1**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768), specifying plugin, goal and execution id as following:

  ```
  mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java@IDEInjector-client
  ```

The command above will only (and only) execute the snippet you posted.

---

As a side note, you probably would need the whole build or phase to be executed for your purpose. In general, such a generation is not meant to be invoked separately (and not even per phase). So, my assumption is that you simply need to run the whole Maven build and - as part of it and as explained above - Maven will take care of this sources generation together with whatever is already foreseen in the POM for its build.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `<phase>` tag, this is bound to the `generate-sources` phase. You can call this phase by doing `mvn generate-sources` from the command line.